# how to convert a 2d path to a 3d shape in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

i need to have the 3d of this: http://jsfiddle.net/dAdKm/ 

but when i use this code:

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(20,20);
shape.bezierCurveTo(20, 100, 150, 100, 150, 20);
shape.moveTo(20,20);
shape.lineTo(20, 100);
shape.lineTo(150, 100);
shape.lineTo(150, 20);

var shape3d = shape.extrude(extrudeSettings);
var shapePoints = shape.createPointsGeometry();
var shapeSpacedPoints = shape.createSpacedPointsGeometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff });
var shapeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(shape3d, material);
```

the result is not same as 2d context result, why? what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shape starts at (20, 20), goes to (150, 20) and then "jumps" back to (20, 20).

Avoid jumping, try this shape definition instead:

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.moveTo(20,20);
shape.bezierCurveTo(20, 100, 150, 100, 150, 20);
shape.lineTo(150, 100);
shape.lineTo(20, 100);
shape.moveTo(20,20);
```